# Python IndexError: list index out of range with long string

Tags: python, list, indexing

My code seems to work with shorter strings, but inexplicably to me gets stuck on others. The function of this is to replace characters with digits, and I have it print out the new string after each part is replaced. Any help you can give me is appreciated, thanks!

By the way, I did look at the similar questions on this and they did not answer my particular question, please don't remove my question.

```
possibleChars = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W',
'X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',
'w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',' ',',','.','?','!','/','\\','[',']','{','}',
'|','<','>',';',':','+','=','-','_','(',')','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','~','`']  #0-92

possibleCharsToDigit = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3',
'4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8',
'9','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3',
'4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3'] #0-92

password = "How is your day today?"

def passwordToDigit(passToConvert):
    passLen = len(passToConvert) #puts the length of the password in a variable
    i = 0 #i is the selected character in the password
    j = 0 #j is the selected possible char, i.e. '0' is 'A' in possibleChars or '1' in possibleCharsToDigit
    while i < passLen:
        if passToConvert[i] == possibleChars[j]:
            passToConvert = passToConvert[0:i] + possibleCharsToDigit[j] + passToConvert[i + 1:]
            i += 1
            print passToConvert
        else:
            j += 1
    print passToConvert

passwordToDigit(password)
```

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set `j = 0` in the `if passToConvert[i] == possibleChars[j]` clause:

```
def passwordToDigit(passToConvert):
    passLen = len(passToConvert) #puts the length of the password in a variable
    i = 0 #i is the selected character in the password
    j = 0 #j is the selected possible char, i.e. '0' is 'A' in possibleChars or '1' in possibleCharsToDigit
    while i < passLen:
        if passToConvert[i] == possibleChars[j]:
            passToConvert = passToConvert[0:i] + possibleCharsToDigit[j] + passToConvert[i + 1:]
            i += 1
            j = 0
            print passToConvert
        else:
            j += 1
    print passToConvert
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are incrementing `j` variable inside the `while` loop, notice that when `j` gets bigger than the length of `possibleCharsToDigit` list then you are trying to access its element with `index out of bounds`.

Answer (score 1):

As you increment `j` within your while loop, without ever resetting it, each time you successfully match a character and move onto the next one. This will cause your code to fail as soon as you have a character earlier in `possibleChars` than a previous one.

To illustrate:

```
passwordToDigit('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP')  #will work correctly
passwordToDigit('BA') #will fail with IndexError
```

### Quick Solution

The quickest solution would be to reset the `j` index when you find a match.

ie

```
# ...
if passToConvert[i] == possibleChars[j]:
    passToConvert = passToConvert[0:i] + possibleCharsToDigit[j] + passToConvert[i + 1:]
    i += 1
    print passToConvert
    j = 0  #Reset tje j index to start searching from beginning
else: 
#...
```

### Dict Solution

You could also spend some time refactoring your code to use a `dict` to map characters to digits as in:

```
import string
charopts = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits[1:] + r'0 ,.?!/\[]{}|<>;:+=-_()@#$%^&*~`'
char2dig = dict((k,str((i+1)%10)) for i,k in enumerate(charopts))

def passwordToDigitDic(passToConvert):
    newpass = '' 
    for c in passToConvert:
        newpass += char2dig[c]
        print(newpass + passToConvert[len(newpass):])

passwordToDigitDic('ABCDEFGH')
passwordToDigitDic('HGEFBCA')
```

<sub>**Note**, if you are ever interested in doing the translation in one go as opposed to step by step with prints, look into the `string.translate` function.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

When i=passLen-1, then you are trying to access passToConvert[i+1], which is out of the range of passToConvert. Hence you are getting this error. Try this:

```
 if passToConvert[i] == possibleChars[j]:
   if i<passLen-1:
        passToConvert = passToConvert[0:i] + possibleCharsToDigit[j] + passToConvert[i + 1:]
   else: 
        passToConvert = passToConvert[0:i] + possibleCharsToDigit[j]
   i += 1
   print passToConvert
```